# How to add autoplay to this slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm begginer with java so i used this slider code and I want to add an autoplay option but i juct can't get it right. Here is the slider i'm using as an example
http://rafbm.github.io/howtomakeaslider/demo.html

Thank you

Comment: Should not be that hard. What have you tried?

Comment: setInterval on every location in code and in every possible way haha:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `setInterval()`. Put this at the end of the document

```
setInterval(function(){
      goToNext();
    },5000);
```

The `goToNext()` function is attached to your "next" button. The above function will trigger it every 5 seconds.

Comment: I have tried that already and it wont work. Not sure if I am right but i think goToNext() is a method so that's a complication

Comment: a basic fiddle would help put a solution together. It would be very easy indeed.

Comment: fidle? as i sad java beginer :/

Comment: jsfiddle is an online code website where you input your code and post the link here, and then other developers can fix it etc [link] http://jsfiddle.net/